# xml schema doesn't link to xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

So I have an xml schema file and I want to show it in the browser using xsl. The problem is in my xml file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSDXSL.xsl"?>
<documento xmlns="http://www.example.org/teste" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/teste ReceitaXSD.xsd">

    <cabecalho>
        <titulo>Receitas Tradicionais</titulo>
    </cabecalho>
</documento>
```

and have the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.01" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="documento">
        <HTML>
            <HEAD>
                <TITLE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cabecalho/titulo" />
                </TITLE>
            </HEAD>
            <BODY>

            <xsl:value-of select="cabecalho/titulo"/>

            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this it appears that the xml doesn't link to my xsl file, because when I try to show my xml file in the browser I get all the text in the xml instead of the value: `<xsl:value-of select="cabecalho/titulo"/>`

Before someone asks this is just a tiny bit of the xml file and I have an xsd file that validates the xml.

Comment: The schema has nothing to do with the XSLT processing the XML. The issue is that your XML is in the default namespace `http://www.example.org/teste`, but your template matches `documento` in no namespace. You'll need to bind the namespace to a prefix and use it in your XPath's (including those in the xsl:value-of's). If you search on `[xslt] default namespace`, you should have plenty of examples.

Comment: So now i have this: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:pre="example.org/teste"; xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">;` and have things like:  `<xsl:value-of select="pre:cabecalho/pre:titulo" />` and it works. Now the problem is that in every xpath i have to add the pre: and i have a big file. There is other way of doing it ?

Comment: Unfortunately in XSLT 1.0 there isn't another way of doing it. If you were able to use XSLT 2.0 you could use [`xpath-default-namespace`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames), but browsers don't natively support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You _could_ use [Saxon-JS](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) to run XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0) in the browser, but I'm not sure what your real world requirements are. (It would also require [Saxon-EE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.8EE) (not free) to export the stylesheets package.)